# Pyramid 1.8 forbidden_view_config return 404

Tags: python, pyramid, basic-authentication

I have a basic application using Pyramid 1.8 where I want to have a forbidden_view_config to challenge the client.

In my views.py I have:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.view import forbidden_view_config
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPUnauthorized
from pyramid.security import forget

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    return {'project': 'odkchallenge'}


@forbidden_view_config(route_name='carlos')
def auth_view(request):
    response = HTTPUnauthorized()
    response.headers.update(forget(request))
    return response
```

In my init.py I have:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('carlos', '/carlos')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

But when I go to http://localhost:6543/carlos I get:

> 404 Not Found The resource could not be found.
>
> /carlos

I been looking at the documentation about forbidden_view_config and it should be like view_config . If I change it to view_config /carlos does not return 404. Any idea why? or what else I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pasted example you are using `forbidden_view_config` without any views containing permissions and thus it is not triggered. If, instead, you used `notfound_view_config` you would at least execute your `auth_view` view.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? How do I add permissions to a view? or can you direct me to somewhere?

Comment: The forbidden view is executed when a `HTTPForbidden` exception is raised within your app, which you can do manually or you can use pyramid's auth system to have exceptions raised automatically based on view permissions `@view_config(permission=..)`. Pyramid's sqlalchemy+url dispatch tutorial goes into this a fair amount and is worth reading if you haven't yet.